# Migrate from Cassandra 0.6 to 2.1 version and retrieve the previous data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I am running an application which uses cassandra 0.6. Now i want to migrate it to cassandra 2.1 version.

I did the following.

- Downloaded the tarball and installed.
- Changed my cluster name as per my configurations
- Pointed the data-file directories, saved caches, commit log to the data previously stored by older version.

In my data-file directories I have few folders with keyspaces say A, B , C, D, system, system_traces where the data was added through thrift api.

A, B, C ,D folders have subfolders such as

```
/.../cassandra/data/A/Standard1-1-Data.db
/.../cassandra/data/A/Standard1-1-Filter.db
/.../cassandra/data/A/Standard1-1-Index.db
```

Same files with B , C , D respectively.

Now when i start my cassandra 2.1 and run cqlsh from command line and connect to cassandra instance. 
I type the command

describe keyspaces;

I get output as system and system_traces .

why is this happening Where did A,B,C, D keyspaces go?? why is my data not getting retrieved? Is my migration right??

If wrong, How do i retrieve the data in those files? How do i access them??

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to directly upgrade from Cassandra 0.6 to 2.1.  You should be able to figure out an upgrade plan if you read through the upgrade guides:

- [DataStax Upgrade Guide](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html)
- [Cassandra 1.2 Upgrading Prerequisites](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/upgrade/upgradeCPrereq_c.html)

Speicifcally, these tidbits of information are significant:

> Cassandra 2.1 is not compatible with Cassandra 1.x SSTables. First
>   upgrade the nodes to Cassandra 2.0.7 or later, start the cluster,
>   upgrade the SSTables, stop the cluster, and then upgrade to Cassandra
>   2.1.

And...

> Cassandra 2.0 is not network- or SSTable-compatible with versions
>   older than 1.2.9. If your version of Cassandra is earlier than 1.2.9
>   and you want to perform a rolling restart, first upgrade the entire
>   cluster to 1.2.9, and then to Cassandra 2.0.

And...

> Data files from Cassandra 0.6 and later are compatible with Cassandra
>   1.2

Basically, you need to upgrade 0.6 to 1.2.9, and then upgrade 1.2.9 to 2.0.7, and then you should be able to upgrade to 2.1.  You might also need to do a little research to find out whether or not you can upgrade to 1.2.9 directly from 0.6 (I don't remember for sure, but I think you might have to upgrade to the lastest 1.1.x before going to 1.2.9).

For each upgrade you do, you'll have to follow the steps listed in the DataStax Upgrade Guide that I mentioned above:

1. Stop the node.
2. Back up your configuration files. Depending on how
   you install the product, these files may be overwritten with default
   values during the installation. After backing up your configuration,
   follow the appropriate installation instructions depending on your
   current installation type.
3. Install the new version of Cassandra. Debian or Ubuntu RHEL or
   CentOS Tarball
4. Configure the new product. Using the backups you made
   of your configuration files, merge any modifications you have
   previously made into the new configuration files for the new
   version. Configuration options change often, so be sure to double
   check the version restrictions for additional steps and changes
   regarding configuration.
5. Start the node.
6. If you are upgrading from a
   major version (for example, from 1.2 to 2.0) or a major point
   release (for example, from Cassandra 2.0 to 2.1), upgrade the
   sstables on each node.

`$ nodetool upgradesstables`

*(#6 is one of the more-important steps that you appear to have skipped)*

7. Check the logs for
   warnings, errors and exceptions. Repeat on each node in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which version of cassandra 0.6.X you are running, and even within the 0.6 patch versions, there are upgrade instructions in NEWS.txt.

At the very least, you will need to upgrade through the latest patch level of each major.minor cassandra release. Cassandra upgrade notes, gotchas, and detailed steps are always documented in NEWS.txt:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/NEWS.txt

You have skipped a lot of steps.  :-)